# What should I do if a flag requires urgency?

Tags: discussion, flags

Yesterday, I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554828/discord-bot-not-running-python-3-8-3) post for moderator intervention since I think that some sensitive information was exposed - I am still not fully sure.

For now, nobody reacted, and the post is still there with the information I consider sensitive, and my flag is pending. It seems like it should be dealt with within hours, and my flag should be marked as either helpful or declined (depending of if I'm right or not).

Although it seems like the API key (or whatever that thing is) has expired, it should not affect how we deal with it in any way. Is there any way that I can mark a flag urgent?

Comment: There are no "urgent" flags. And if they existed, they would be misused all the time.

Comment: You are bringing additional attention to the post you want to redact. You could have suggested an edit in the meantime. But in any case, it's the poster's responsibility, and it's always too late once a post is published anyway.

Comment: You can edit out sensitive information yourself effectively hiding from anyone but someone who know where to look... And later moderators can wipe history...

Comment: @yivi should this be a feature request then? I fully understand that hard limitations need to apply.

Comment: The preferred way to handle this is to *immediately* edit the post and remove the sensitive information. Then flag for moderator attention and point at the edit you made explaining *what* is the problem and that you want that edit to be removed. However, not all data is sensitive data - I once flagged for an revision removal because it contained a private key and the response to the flag was that there no personally identifiable information (PII), so no need to do anything. I didn't know better at the time but I took note.

Comment: @yivi There's no urgent flags in the system, but some are arguably more urgent than others. Plagiarism isn't urgent, but a user going on an R/A comment spree is arguably urgent because it can't wait. Accidentally shared user info is also urgent, because time means more eyes see it and could potentially abuse it. Fortunately in this case, it's a Discord question, and the old tokens can be invalidated to prevent abuse, but that assumes OP is responsive. Urgency doesn't exist in the system, but some flags still require more urgent handling than others.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, there is no way to mark a flag as "urgent". If such a feature were to be added, people would use it indiscriminately and it would lose all meaning. If everything is urgent, nothing is urgent anymore.

Moderator flags that you raise persist in the moderator flag queue until they are handled. Stack Overflow gets more than 2500 flags per day, every day, so we simply cannot make any guarantees that a flag will be handled within hours.

Regarding this particular flag (the sharing of supposedly sensitive information), I find it very hard to get excited about redacting this using moderator tools when the original poster doesn't even seem to care. Besides, once the information has gotten out there, even if only for a matter of hours, the problem really needs to be addressed in a different way (e.g., changing the password or API key), rather than simple redaction.

Furthermore, your flag didn't convey very much information. The full text was:

> Sensitive information exposed (I think)

*What specific information* is exposed in the question that you think is sensitive? In this particular case, no moderator had happened to have a chance to look at your flag. But if I had, I would have been confused and frustrated because I have no idea what in that massive block of output is supposedly sensitive. I don't know what you think needs to be redacted.

It would be preferable to mention *within the text of the moderator flag* what specific information you think is sensitive and needs to be removed. It would be even better if you went ahead and submitted an edit removing/anonymizing the sensitive information alongside your flag. That not only eliminates any doubt about what information needs to be redacted, but simplifies the process of redaction for moderators.

Comment: Re *"people would use it indiscriminately"*: That is preventable by paying in reputation points, e.g. 2% of current total reputation points and a minimum of 30 reputation points. ***Super flags***

Comment: I understand where you're going with the suggestion, @Peter, and can imagine variations on it (like having the flag marked as "helpful" would refund the reputation loss). However, tying reputation points to moderator flags in *any* form or fashion is a bridge that I simply cannot cross.

Comment: For the record, with discord.py, `client.run()` takes a Discord API token. Anyone with access to the token has unrestricted access to the bot. I edited out the token and warned OP - redacting is possibly useless at this point. The damage is already done

Comment: @PeterMortensen then can I also purchase an extra **super flag** for €9,99?

Comment: @Luuklag You can even **sponsor a moderator** for €999,99!