# Is it mandatory for candidates to answer the moderator election questionnaire?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

If a candidate who has nominated oneself chooses not to answer the questionnaire [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399106/2020-community-moderator-election-questionnaire), is the candidate disqualified because of that or is still eligible?

Comment: To be fair, I only expect a positive answer to this. If this question emerged becaue of a specific submission, I imagine that the community moderators are falling on the safe side and waiting for everyone to post their answers to the questionaire before the nomination phase ends.

Comment: Per the [election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) sidebar, in the nomination phase *"Nominees are required to construct a small, freely editable introduction to describe why they might make a good community moderator."* Completing the questionnaire is *not* listed as required.

Comment: Also as per the question collection [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398884/2020-moderator-election-qa-question-collection): *"Participation is completely voluntary."*

Comment: @Nick While your conclusion is correct, you reached it only by accident. In context, the quoted statement just means that participating in question *submission* is completely voluntary.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think that's correct..., question submission is _obviously_ voluntary, there is no need for it to be explicitly stated as otherwise they'd end up with hundreds of thousands of questions to choose from. I read it as meaning participation [in the Q&A] is completely voluntary.

Comment: A candidate could give nonsense answers, so why bother to require it? People will vote accordingly and if they don't, this would hint at larger problems. No answer to the questionaire is also an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The questionnaire is *technically* optional. A candidate will not be disqualified from standing for election if they fail to answer the questionnaire.

The only thing that is required is the nomination statement, which is what appears on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/election).

However, you as voters should demand that candidates participate, and we as your existing moderators expect them to do so. Ultimately, a candidate can choose not to do it, but that should factor into your decision when voting. Transparency, clear communication, and responsibility are all important characteristics in a site moderator.

With that said, I'd note that it's a bit too early to start worrying at this stage of the nomination process. The questionnaire is pretty long, and we want thoughtful answers, so those often take a while to prepare. The nominees still have several more days.

Comment: Why not make it mandatory?

Comment: Frankly, @Yatin, how one approaches filling out the questionnaire says a lot.

Comment: When I ran it said something like "questionnaire (optional)" above the box. In other words, the candidates know that they don't have to fill it out to submit. (I'm not sure how long it's looked like this, however.)

Comment: @Laurel You ran this year; the election system was completely revamped earlier this year before election cycles began. The questionnaire is now inlined as part of the nomination. Previously, when this answer was posted, it was a separate Q&A on Meta, and not part of the nomination statement. But, yes, what *hasn't* changed is that the questionnaire is still optional.