# Is it gaming the system when a moderator candidate submits their nomination at the last moment?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, abuse

In a probably unprecedented (and definitely antidemocratic) move [one of the moderator candidates of the current (2021 Fall-on-the-Northern-Hemisphere) election posted their nomination 53 seconds before the nomination phase ended](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69621918/revisions).

There are three main problems here. The first is that comments can only be posted on a candidate's nomination page during the nomination phase, so this "tactical" move prevented all kinds of discussion (most importantly, scrutiny) from all the folks who bother to look at nomination pages.

The second problem is that the user didn't even bother to answer the questionnaire, which could've been addressed in inquisitive comments -- if the "tactical" move hadn't prevented leaving comments, see previous point about scrutiny.

Finally, intentionally gaming the election system is the most antidemocratic thing I can think of. It is a slap in the face for both the community, and fellow nominees who have made the effort of submitting a legitimate nomination with ample room for discussion and criticism.

So my question is this: what if the candidate (sporting a 40/40 candidate score; voting masses love that!) gets elected? How can we trust a moderator whose very first action even before being elected was gaming the very systems we have in place to try and ensure democratic elections? And can we do something to prevent such abuse of nominations in the future?

Comment: It might be unprecedented, but it certainly wasn't unpredictable...

Comment: What do you mean by that, Nick?

Comment: @AndrasDeak several predictions in chat for that event.

Comment: I mean, a large portion of the voters care very little or don't even see the questionnaire, why subject yourself to grilling from people who do when you can just go through to the final stage with a blank slate.

Comment: @Nick I understand _why_ someone would want to game the system. But allegedly we're looking for mods who are "patient and fair", "lead by example" and "show respect for their fellow community members in their actions and words". Kind of the opposite of "gaming the system". We expect better from our mods, or at least we're supposed to expect better from them.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Oh I agree that's what we _should_ expect from them, but not everyone plays nice and any advantage is... an advantage

Comment: One might assume good faith: the candidate didn't know that the comments would be locked.

Comment: One might assume good faith, but I don't feel terribly gullible today.

Comment: Maybe you can post your questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412176/2021-community-moderator-election). It might give some purpose to the existence of that Meta stub.

Comment: I think it's awfully clever. Some candidates have gotten some rather nasty accusations that couldn't really be backed up, any way.

Comment: I personally would go in the opposite direction. Leave discussion to the election chat. Remove any perceived advantage due to when you post by having the discussion somewhere that doesn't go away when the phase changes. Did any of the commenters *not* visit the election chat?

Comment: Only candidate with the [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) badge, isn't it ironic.

Comment: Something in me says this is the perfect candidate. He knows the system well enough to game it  ... might be handy for hunting down sock puppets.

Comment: @rene You convinced me. Moved him to the top. Hope he wins!!!  Andras, If the system can be gamed, don't blame the gamer, blame the system.

Comment: Some might argue that *anyone* foolish enough to volunteer for a non-paying *job* (for that is what it is), one where the amount of responsibility greatly outweighs the amount of power isn't quite fit for ***any*** job :D  Perhaps the greatest punishment would be to win the election

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Aren't we all?(volunteeering to do non paying job of answering, reviewing questions, cleaning SO's mess)

Comment: @TheMaster: of course you're right, and we're all a bit nuts for dedicating our time and energies to this quest, but for moderators, it's a matter of degree.

Comment: Meh, if there is an expectation that nominations must be submitted a certain time period before voting opens this should be enforced by the system

Comment: Related to the 2nd problem, see [*Is it mandatory for candidates to answer the moderator election questionnaire?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399206)

Comment: @CodyGray Assuming good faith is important. We should do so here. However, I'd be surprised if the candidate didn't know comments were locked once the election began. They [ran for SO moderator in 2018](//stackoverflow.com/election/10#candidate-7311767), and were elected on [datascience.se] in 2019. The old election system also locked comments once the election began, or at least that it did so in both 2019 and 2020 (I don't recall personally testing it in other years). So, I'd give the explanation of "didn't know" a low probability. That doesn't mean we shouldn't still assume good faith.

Comment: I wonder how many voters even look at the comments. I happened to read through them during the nomination phase, but when I went to cross-reference them during voting, I found them hard to find. I imagine that more casual voters who weren't looking for them would miss the comments entirely. If I'm right, this likely only has a marginal impact. (Personally, I'd like to see the nomination comments far more discoverable; the discussions in the comments can be really insightful.)

Comment: My good faith assumption here is simply that they were on the fence about nominating themselves, and were rushed to squeeze in a nomination before the deadline. If this was purely strategic, I imagine they'd have included answers to the questionnaire. Otherwise, it seems like a pretty poor strategy; I can't imagine someone who didn't take the time to answer the questionnaire getting much traction.

Comment: @JeremyCaney - I specifically put him last _because_ he didn't fill out the questionnaire.

Comment: Also related: [Make moderator election questionnaire mandatory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222154/make-moderator-election-questionnaire-mandatory)

Comment: @SomethingDark: I specifically didn’t even _include_ them in my vote because of that.

Comment: @SomethingDark And that's the most appropriate response to this: if you don't like the action(s), vote accordingly

Comment: @Makyen The election system has been *completely* revamped recently. It is reasonable to assume that the old bugs/limitations had been removed/fixed.

Comment: @CodyGray In many places, I'd assume that revamping a system would substitute new bugs/unintentional limitations for the old ones. Disabling the comments during the election phase appeared to be an intentional choice. As such, it's something I' would have assumed would *not* change. I think it *should* change, primarily because there's no longer a separate MSO question containing the questionnaire answers on which discussion could continue. Such discussion, even during the election, has been valuable and important in prior years.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, sorry I have caused so much consternation.  Mondays are the busiest day of the week, and I am not a fast writer. Was there some philosophical point in this year's questionnaire that you did not find at least somewhat covered in my 2018 questionnaire?

Comment: @StephenRauch The idea is not that Andras should individually receive personal feedback about this, and the issue is much larger than just him, as the votes should at least somewhat communicate.

Comment: This post is not nice. This is totally within the rules. There is a line, he was on the right side of it. Any line will necessitate some being closer than others. The point of the line is to decide the point in which it's no longer acceptable.

Comment: It was confusing at first to see no answers for this year's questions and only a brief "who am I statement". The timings then led me to think that perhaps they had a last minute change of heart and rushed to get their nomination in. I felt like I didn't have a feel for the candidate's handling of situations, in the immediately digestible way the nomination questions present. **However**, the link to 2018 election meant I could track to their answers then, and I rather like many of those responses. They gave me a better "feel" for the candidate.

Comment: it seems that the system is flawed, rather than the candidate. What should be the system would be not allowing comments until AFTER the candidates are known, and then allowing comments for a set period. That way, and only that way, can people know all the candidates when commenting and have the same time to comment on all of them.

Comment: So wait a sec, Stephen vows to spend at least 30 minutes per day to SO, but didn't find time to complete the questionnaire and self-nominate for the whole week until the very last second?

Comment: If doing something jist before the deadline causes a problem, that is a problem with the process. The process should be fixed.

Comment: Could Stephen predict that some members of the public would be wondering the reason for the last second nomination? Shouldn't that detail be included in the nomination text? Shouldn't we crave moderators that err on the side of being explanatory rather than provocative? If there was no gaming here, then I would have expected an explanation as to why the nomination text did not include answers to the questionnaire.  If there is a legitimate reason for not having time to post the nomination days earlier, then I would expect to read that too.

Comment: This isn't unprecedented, this has happened on other SE sites. It is a known flaw in the election system, which can be exploited intentionally but also by chance or circumstance. It's not that easy to fix without prolonging the election period, which SE was rather reluctant to consider in the past.

Comment: @StephenRauch A question for you, then: You mention visiting Meta every day for the last three years or so, but you haven't posted on Meta once in that time.  Apart from reviews (of which you've done many), your Meta activity in the past couple years appears limited to a handful of comments and some minor housekeeping on tag wikis.  Would you expect that to change if you were elected?  Why or why not?

Comment: @AndrasDeak You never know what someone is going through, it might have been unintentional, if you ask him, he will probably say that he is glad he was able to submit his candidature. I am not extremely gullible but he should be given one chance as he is already a mod on another website, his work is of great importance, let's appreciate it rather than pointing it out. I am a college student and I have literally missed submitting my assignments by 2 minutes, or just submitted it a minute ago, that can happen. Sometimes you get busy with personal problems but you still have to move on.

Comment: @AndrasDeak maybe check the definition of "democracy". Hint: it doesn't mean that only candidates you like get on the ballot or win.

Comment: "How can we trust a moderator..." The same way to trust anyone else, by actions of course. Now moderator actions aren't necessarily public, but that's another story.

Comment: Frankly i see having this discussion about the candidate during the election in this way is... problematic... regardless of your stance on the actual candidate. No other candidate is getting this kind of publicity. There's certainly things you could bring up about other candidates that could be just as "troubling" to others that simply won't be because it didn't happen a day ago. If we want to discuss changing the process to avoid a candidate being able to avoid a discussion, lets discuss that. We don't need  to make this about a specific candidate.

Comment: This isn't some new election process, it's the same process that has been in place for a decade with only a few minor QoL tweaks. The rules were in place, lines were drawn, and all of this was done above the table. If there's a problem with the process, that should be the focus.

Comment: The most important decision SO needs to make is what to call this sort of behavior. My vote is for "**Slowest Gun in the West**".

Comment: @KevinB "...If we want to discuss changing the process to avoid a candidate being able to avoid a discussion, lets discuss that." Specifically let's discuss it after the election (in order to avoid interference).

Comment: It is only Fall (autumn) in the [Northern Hemisphere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Northern_Hemisphere#Noun). The Australians are not amused.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this helps the nominee.  How does this increase a candidate's chances of being elected? As far as I can tell, this can only *hurt* someone's chances; how is this malicious or "gaming"?

Comment: @BSMP reducing the chances for one candidate, increases it for the rest

Comment: @BSMP comments under nominations pool the community's resources for pulling up answers and behaviour that might count against the nominee, and at least pressure them into explaining themself. See for instance the way Zoe was somewhat brutally questioned thanks to her volunteering as an early adopter. Without this discussion _right there with the nomination_ the community lacks information. What we're left with is a self-advertising blurb. The nominee spared a lot of work putting together a convincing nomination, and avoided being asked hairy questions. Surely you can understand my view.

Comment: This still sounds like it would cause them to *lose* votes, not gain them. Unless you think most people would vote for someone specifically because there's less information available?

Comment: @JDB We already have an opposite for "Fastest Gun in the West": "Slowest Cheater in the East". See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite

Comment: @CodyGray :facepalm:

Comment: Did never before somebody not fill out the questionnaire? This question could have done a bit more research. I can hardly believe it that in all the years all people always answered all the questions. But maybe that is a first. In that case the question would be how optional the questionnaire really is.

Comment: @Trilarion you are now completely ignoring or missing my point. The problem is not the questionnaire. It's a combination of a subpar nomination and intentional prevention of critical comments under the nomination. You can disagree with my objection to this, but insistently ignoring my point is somewhat... suboptimal.

Comment: Not even the "subpar" part. It could be the most stellar nomination the world has ever seen, and I'd still object to the willful sabotaging of the peer review system provided by the nomination phase. (But in that case I'd be easier to convince that the timing was accidental.)

Comment: I'm also not very happy with your timing. It could well be seen as an attempt to interfere in the election and influence the result. But this is just a comment, not an answer. There are already a lot.

Comment: @Trilarion Trying to influence the result is well within the rules of SO, to cite a well-liked fact about the nomination. If it's within the rules, surely you absolutely cannot argue against it?

Comment: I will only endorse this candidate if they change their name to **Votey McVoteface**.

Comment: If only the mass of men put as much needed critical thinking into governmental candidates behavior -- the world would be a much better place... Here, the issue boils down to one of "Intent". While we cannot know what was in the mind of the late submitter -- if the intent was to game the system, then the concerns raised are 100% valid. If it was an honest "just saw nominations taking place..." filing, then no. Without some tell (such as metadata on a piece of the submission, etc..) we are left to ponder the likelihood and probability of one verses the other.

Comment: I haven't been following the election--is my understanding of this correct? Candidates receive a score (based on reviews?), but that scoring is locked at the same time as the candidate application deadline, and all candidates start at full points. If that's the case, then there is no contesting that a last minute entry will have the highest score. It would make much more sense to continue the rating for a period after candidacy declaration (to allow ratings to even out) or to set initial scores at 0 (to encourage candidates to apply early)

Comment: @Mars That is not correct.  The candidate score is based half on reputation and half on which of 20 badges the candidate has.  So mine is 32, because I have 13k rep and 19 of the 20 badges, so 13 + 19 = 32.  It doesn't, unfortunately, take anything else into account.

Comment: @RyanM Thanks! So the only possible advantage for a last minute submission is that the user avoids comments on their candidacy?

Comment: @Mars Unfortunately, literally *none* of your assumptions are true. The candidate score is not based on reviews. It doesn't take reviews into account at all. As Ryan said, it is based half on reputation and half on specific badges that the candidate may have earned. Furthermore, the candidate score displayed beneath their nomination does *not* lock in. It updates forever. If you look at nominations for candidates in past elections, their candidate scores are their *current* candidate scores, not their scores when they nominated themselves. And the candidate score doesn't start at full points.

Comment: Yes, the only advantage of a last-minute submission is that no one can comment on their nomination, since comments close to the public after the nomination period ends.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for the clarification. If that's the case, then it does sound like a strategic move to submit an application right before deadline--one easily alleviated by extending comments past the nomination phase. No guarantee that the candidate in question did it to game the system, but there is also no debating that it's a gamey part of the system. For that, I can understand why OP feels as they do

Comment: @StephenRauch Do you expect voters to 1) know you ran for moderator in 2018, and 2) know that they can go find your Q&A responses there? Are all the questions all the same?

Comment: @TylerH regarding 1): he links to the 2018 election saying he participated.

Comment: @TylerH I mean, the nomination includes a link to the election in 2018. Any voter who can read can easily figure that out

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ah thanks, we've seen approximately 6 years worth of discussion since the nomination period closed so I forgot about that. Still, he only mentions he ran, not that "you can see my answers to the Q&A there".

Comment: I think we've finally found a place where the politics are even _more_ vicious than the academy because the stakes are even _lower_.  Sadly, that place is _here_.

Comment: @TylerH Nearly all questions are different than in 2018.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Thanks for checking; bad news it seems.

Comment: The election is over and the candidate which nominated himself at the last minute got the most votes. If it was gaming the system it was successful. But most of the answers seem to suggest that it rather wasn't. What is maybe missing is a time period between nomination and election. Elections really shouldn't start right after the nomination period. This case may also highlight that the importance of the questionnaire may be overvalued. Maybe most voters actually don't read that much from the election page, before making up their decision.

Comment: This post doesn't make much sense. You start with the idea that uninformed masses will just look at the score and vote. In that case why would answering the questionnaire matter? Why would having comments below it matter? And more importantly, how is it anti democratic when it's well within the rules and, like it or not, every vote (as uninformed as it may be) is worth the same?

Answer (score 118):

## ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Is this even an issue?  You can look at their nomination post/sales pitch for why they think they'd make a good moderator through the end of the voting phase.  If everything they've done and said in the nomination post would otherwise lead you to believe that they're alright, then there's not much other reason to vote differently on their nomination.

In the end, this doesn't really *change* a whole lot - you're voting on who *you* think would be best as a moderator.  If their action to get their submission in literally as the door was closing reflects poorly in your eyes - which, I need to stress, **is still entirely allowed**, even if it leaves a sour taste in your mouth - then you should take that into consideration when you vote.

Remember:  An assignment that is due by 11:59PM Sunday evening can take submissions all the way up to 11:58:59PM.

Edit: [Looks like they got full credit for the assignment too](https://www.opavote.com/results/5141741653983232).  Guess there really is no such thing as "bad publicity", is there...?

Comment: I'm trying to vote for who I think would be best as a moderator, but I can't find your avatar! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's an issue. No, just because it's "legal" doesn't make it ethical or acceptable. It's not about _my_ opinion. I know what I think. But surely you're aware that elections are largely decided by uninformed swarms of users who see notifications on the main site telling them to vote. If we don't even try to uphold the appearance of giving a fair choice, what are we even doing with the elections? But of course, if the community (by which I mean meta for want of a better forum) thinks this is fine then it's fine, and the site will be in the kind of hands that it deserves.

Comment: @CodyGray I hate you, take my upvote <3

Comment: @AndrasDeak:  This is why I've been referring to the moderator elections less tongue-in-cheek as a popularity contest, since, well, it's usually the more popular or more prominent candidate that gets nominated.  Going back to my example about an assignment due at 11:59PM, if someone gets it in by 11:58:59PM, *they are still on time*.  What you really should be looking at is if they answered the questionnaire (to your satisfaction), or if their actions in moderating with the tools that they have indicate to you that they'll continue to do so or do better with diamond powers.

Comment: We fundamentally disagree so I don't want to drag this thread out any longer, so just one last point: the "tactical" move I object to is not along the "capable mod" axis, it's along the "responsible mod" axis. If (when) a moderator screws up, they'll have to answer to the community. They _should_. Some always do, some never do. I want the ones that always do. A mod candidate who sidesteps meta scrutiny for selfish reasons (because there can only be selfish reasons) I expect to give the same cold shoulder when they need to be held accountable by the community.

Comment: @AndrasDeak:  It sounds like you've got the data points you wanted from this candidate's nomination.  I literally do not know what else I can tell you here.

Comment: "*Remember: An assignment that is due by 11:59PM Sunday evening can take submissions all the way up to 11:58:59PM.*" This is not really a good metaphor. A homework assignment typically does not affect the future of your classmates in the class or school system, and your classmates don't typically review your homework assignments before you turn them in.

Comment: @TylerH:  My point is that everyone here is making a whole big deal over the technicality of *when* the assignment was submitted, not what was *in* it.  My point is for people here to make a concerted effort to evaluate the candidate on their merits, not when they nominated themselves.  Note that I'm being meticulously careful on this point, since I feel like a lot of people want to jump on a bandwagon and either laud or crucify a candidate for some specific reason, when the simplest thing may be to...just...not vote for them...if you think this is unbecoming of a moderator.

Comment: @user4581301 why exterminate, when you can *assimilate*? We have perfectly serviceable [Collectives](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_Collective).

Comment: To extend on the closing remarks: Personally, if an assignment is due by 11:59PM Sunday evening, I'll likely submit it at 11:58:59PM—even if, in practice, I actually _completed_ the assignment a week prior. That gives me every opportunity to reevaluate my answer. (Acknowledging that self nominations _can_ be edited.) (Of course, just last week, I attempted to submit an assignment at 11:58PM, only to encounter a technical roadblock that prevented the submission from going through. YMMV.)

Comment: I would take this behavior as a useful signal for determining how to vote on the candidate, rather than a call to pitchforks.

Comment: @Makoto "Note that I'm being meticulously careful on this point, since I feel like a lot of people want to jump on a bandwagon and either laud or crucify a candidate for some specific reason, when the simplest thing may be to...just...not vote for them...if you think this is unbecoming of a moderator " I think this is what the OP was saying. Your answer and comments are reflecting that back. Which is fine, but not ellipsis-level revelatory.

Comment: @Makoto Personally I suspect the issue is not *just* "when", but a combination of "when" and the fact that, due to "when", no commentary was allowed due to comments getting auto locked, preventing anyone from criticizing/requesting elaboration on a particular candidate's lackluster nomination.

Comment: Those concerned with impropriety may consider such a tactic *underhanded*, a behavior that's really not appropriate in a moderator... and something that most people who visit the election page will be blissfully unaware of. Note that users who are not eligible to self-nominate *don't get a notification* about the nomination stage... they only get a notification about the *voting* stages. Some folks are recommending we allow commentary during the voting stages, which I generally support, along with other adjustments to the process.

Comment: @TylerH:  I honestly can't see it that much different from the candidates that never did answer the questionnaire or respond to questions or feedback from the community.  I recall it being seen or regarded as equivalent to them simply ignoring the community and probably raising questions of fitness, but *beyond that*, I don't think this should be regarded as *such* a big deal.

Comment: @Makoto I agree the framing of this Q&A thread in particular seems over the top. However, the underlying concern of not having the opportunity to comment/directly address a specific candidate's nomination remains.

Comment: @TylerH:  It has always been a problem with every election that Stack Exchange has ever run in the history of ever.  It has never been an *issue* until now. I'm perplexed why this issue can't resolve itself naturally and why we have to have such an outcry about it.

Comment: @Makoto What do you mean by "naturally"? System rules/designs don't change themselves... people have to make those changes. As for why you've never seen such outcry from it, perhaps you just don't remember/didn't notice if it ever occurred in previous elections. Or perhaps it was the quality/contents of *this* specific nomination that highlighted for the first time how it could *be* a *problem* (or *issue* or whatever word you would like to use).

Comment: @TylerH:  The natural thing is to not vote for the candidate who you believe did something underhanded.  It's like...that's really the only real recourse here.  So what if they got their nomination in *just* before the buzzer?  Read up on them to see if they're otherwise qualified, and if they aren't, just don't vote for them.  I just *really* cannot see the point in shouting about this when honestly the fix is to just not vote for a candidate you don't believe is fit for the role.

Comment: @Makoto "*The natural thing is to not vote for the candidate who you believe did something underhanded.*" This misses the entire point. You may sit comfortably in your ivory tower knowing *you* diligently exercise due process, but those interested in ensuring the system is safeguarded from potential abuse have to worry about the lowest common denominator. "*It's like...that's really the only real recourse here.*" Sure, if you... ignore the existing of this and several other questions on MSO and MSE putting forth other options for recourse.

Comment: @TylerH:  Again - this is why I stress that this whole voting and candidacy exercise is more like a popularity contest than anything with any real rigor.  Anyone could simply game the system and make it work to their advantage if they *really* wanted to, and the only way that this can be corrected is if the people participating in the process identified that and took action against it.  But again, your sentiment here implies that there was actually some kind of grave sin or offense that absolutely must be patched immediately lest we unleash anarchy.

Comment: @TylerH:  I won't disagree that the system isn't perfect and could definitely do with a few tweaks here and there.  The angst you're describing is a lack of an opportunity to ask the candidate questions on their nomination page.  I'm calling that expressly a data point to use when evaluating their fit for this role.  So I would simply encourage that you do so as there is really no need to make mountains out of molehills here.

Comment: @Makoto Argumentum ad absurdum? Really? One can notice a problem and want to solve it without it being a "grave sin threatening to unleash anarchy". You're just doubling down on the position of it being fine just because you can't be bothered. That's fine for you, but get out of everyone else's way, please.

Answer (score 101):

> ...  intentionally games the system?

I think this assumption is all wrong. I find it strange that it can be considered as such. The system had a deadline for nomination, and the nomination was done before that deadline. So there is no gaming involved.

Where do you read that a nomination should be done X seconds before deadline? And what is this X? Here X was 53 seconds which you apparently dislike. Would 120 seconds be okay. 3600 seconds? ... And if X isn't written anywhere, who decides its value? You?

It's simply incorrect to call this for gaming. A deadline is a deadline.

Further, why do you assume that it's an advantage? Maybe it's really a disadvantage as the candidate didn't get any time to discuss with voters and convince voters to vote for the candidate. Perhaps it's simply a missed opportunity due to a late decision. Something that will hurt the candidate more than it will benefit the candidate.

And a missing questionnaire is not "gaming", either. No way. It might hurt the candidate, as voters would have liked to read it. That's the candidate's problem, though. But "gaming"... no, it's not.

If anyone is to blame, it must be the system. Maybe there should have been a time period after the nomination deadline where comments were still allowed. But that's a different discussion.

Comment: It’s also worth noting that the early feedback offered in the comments gives candidates an opportunity to refine their candidate statement in order to address weaknesses or misunderstandings—an opportunity this candidate did not receive. Those improvements are almost certainly more visible to most voters than the comments themselves.

Comment: "Maybe there should have been a time period after the nomination deadline where comments were still allowed." Sounds like the obvious way out. In many real life elections, there is such a time period. Not saying that we strictly need it here.

Comment: Exactly. It's not gaming the system; it's simply a broken system. The fault is entirely on whoever designed the system. To even conceive of the question requires switching your brain out of programming mode and into social politics mode.

Comment: @TechInquisitor: Gaming a broken system is still gaming it. Saying it's not is like saying "I wasn't hacking that server! It's their fault for having vulnerabilities."

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Outside of laws written by technologically ignorant legislators, there is no distinction between what a system allows you to do and what that system implies you are authorized to do.

Comment: @TechInquisitor: That is absolutely false. A system that allows me to, say, log in as another user by putting `' or 1=1; --` as my password does not imply I am authorized to do that. Even if it were true, it would have no bearing on the point about gaming broken systems.

Comment: Easy solution: Next time make the deadline 5 minutes earlier.  That'll fix the problem!  (My friend Zeno suggested this, he's thought about this kind of thing a lot.)

Answer (score 37):

I'm hesitant to add another answer saying essentially the same thing as the other two, but as a candidate in this election who is directly impacted by the at-the-wire entry, I figure my perspective can add some insight to the discussion.

And rather than repeating what Makoto [said in his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412344/1161484), I'll just quote the most eloquent part of it:

> ## ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Speaking for myself, I'm glad there is another strong competitor and will fully support their election if they win. After all, the two moderators elected will have run against four competitors, a much harder challenge than being in the top 40%.

I'll also quote in agreement with [another candidate's response in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53271909) immediately following the last-minute entry:

> Well Played!

My only disappointment is that there were not more last minute entries.

Comment: I suppose if I ever run, I'll self-nominate at the last second too so that I don't get roasted like Zoe did in the comments.

Comment: @mickmackusa make sure you let me know when you nominate so I can get an umbrella to protect me from the flying pigs... :)

Comment: @mickmackusa Maybe you won't get roasted. I nominated myself early and it wasn't so bad.

Comment: Fortunately for you, we have very different personas on SO. @Dha

Answer (score 30):

I don't know whether or not they "intentionally gamed the system", but I don't really care. All I care about is the end result. Before seeing this meta post, I read through their nomination statement and I noticed three things:

1. They didn't fill in the questionnaire. (bad)
2. They aren't very active on meta. (bad)
3. They're the only candidate with a score of 40/40. (good, arguably)

So, I wanted to ask the candidate about #1 and #2 (I didn't know/remember that comments are locked after the nomination phase) but I couldn't. I don't know whether or not they did that on purpose and as I said above, I don't really care. The end result is: neither I nor other users had the chance to address those two points with the candidate. And specifically for that reason, **I decided not to vote for them**.

Answer (score 21):

I don't see how posting the nomination at the last second could possibly have a positive effect for Stephen.

People who really care about the questionnaire and the comments on the nomination won't like that he did it that way, and probably won't vote for him because of it.

People who don't care about the questionnaire and the comments on the nomination won't have read them anyway, and they'll vote however they would have voted regardless of when the nomination was posted, if they vote at all.

Maybe it's just me, but the nomination post is not the most important thing to me anyway. Looking through the person's profile to see how they normally act is more valuable to me than reading a carefully prepared example of their best behavior. (If there isn't much there to see either, that's not a good sign for me.)

Comment: "I don't see how posting the nomination at the last second could possibly have a positive effect..." Agreed. But maybe the rationale of the candidate was that posting the nomination at the last minute would not have a decisively strong negative effect either. It could have been some kind of I don't think it's worth the effort consideration.

Comment: @Trilarion I think that's definitely a reasonable interpretation. Maybe it really won't have a strong negative effect. I do think any effect at all will be negative, though. Giving people the impression that they don't think it's worth the effort doesn't seem like it would add much appeal to a candidate. I don't know, though. Some people probably like the idea of a moderator who won't really do much. ;-)

Comment: "People who really care about the questionnaire and the comments on the nomination won't like that he did it that way, and probably won't vote for him because of it."
This is exactly how I felt and what lead to my vote. I put my trust in the people voting; we all know the rules, too. The candidate didn't really thrill or stand out to me so it was a fairly easy pass. This is like a billionaire from NYC running for US president and does nothing but throw money at the system, only for the system to go "Uhh..what? No thanks." and said candidate shrugs and walks away.

Comment: @chrisbyte Huh? I thought that billionaire won in 2016..

Comment: @Scratte I'm talking about Bloomberg, sorry, I should have clarified!

Answer (score 18):

If you believe this nominee's actions were disingenuous, you should take that into account when casting your vote.

You make a good point that drive by voting is mostly influenced by candidate score - and this is highly unlikely to change depending on how early or late the user nominated themselves.

For those of us in the know, we can make an informed decision based on the user's actions and the content (or lack thereof) of their nomination now. Since no rules were technically broken, you are unlikely to see any action taken against the user regardless of election outcomes, but there are a couple of things we can do before the next election:

1. Make it compulsory for the user to submit a questionnaire with non-empty responses. In the (unlikely) event of someone responding to the questionnaire with chum, those can be reported as "joke nominations". We want to make sure nominees adequately convey what they stand for and what issues are important to them.
2. Make comments available and within immediate eyeshot at all stages of the election. Comments provide additional helpful information, allow better clarity into the user's thought processes and help make more informed decisions by vetting candidates. Comment vote counts can be hidden if required.

Simple tweaks to an already pretty good system can go a long way in transparent and fair elections (especially to candidates) in the years to come.

Comment: "Make it compulsory for the user to submit a questionnaire with non-empty responses." Not sure this will increase the number of applicants if we require a filled questionnaire. Isn't not answering the questions also an answer?

Comment: @Trilarion if it were an answer but didn't answer the question, it should be flagged NAA :p

Comment: But that's special for Q&A, i.e. the production of meaningful content. Elections are political and producing words is not the same as producing content. If politicians would be paid by the amount of words they produce they would all be millionaires. I'd say that in this case no answer is a very clear answer.

Answer (score 16):

It's a good observation. However, I think you are little bit fast to assume malicious intent. I'd say that it is quite possible that Stephen just remembered the last minute that he had forgot.

Your last point about being antidemocratic by following the explicit wording of rules but disobeying the obvious intent behind them is a valid point. However, it does require that it was done intentionally. And a philosophy that is (or perhaps was) strong here is "assume good intent until proven otherwise".

But the fact that you cannot post comments is an issue, but I think it's more of a problem with the rules rather than the candidate. The comment section should be open for a time period after the deadline.

Comment: Indeed, perhaps if there would be no possibility for comments putting you on the chopping block this person would have posted the nomination a lot sooner; I would have also been taken aback by the comments under Zoe's nomination to be honest, that might have been a trigger to make this decision.

Comment: **"it's more of a problem with the rules than the candidate"**. I agree 100% with that! There should be at least a 1 week wait period between the nomination period and the election period.

Answer (score 15):

There are other possible reasons for that. I submitted my nomination for an election on one of the other sites I'm involved in less than five minutes before the end of the nomination period; I wasn't trying to game the system, I was just conflicted about running at all because of what happened to Monica.

Comment: Did you half-ass the nomination, even though you had known full well from earlier election attempts how nominations work, and what content is required from a successful candidate? (Just to judge context/relevance here.)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I wouldn't say that it was the greatest nomination of all time, but I did put effort into it.

Answer (score 9):

Stephen Rauch said he was busy that day: that's good enough for me.  He knows the system and wants to help: why would he be turned away from volunteering on this site? It is a very large turnoff to be presumed guilty of some perceived violation of ethics when in fact one is not at all.  It is unfortunate that this question were created in this manner - instead of simply recommending a change to the rules to either

- require posting all facets of a nomination
- allow comments after the nomination deadline

The candidate in question wants to help out: he was aware of the deadline and met the requirements. I'm a heavy [end]-user of this site and appreciate interested volunteers. Bashing one of them that does want to help the community is a tough thing to see.

Comment: Nominations started on October 11th. Election started on the 18th. You, just like him and me, got a notification of both. He said he was busy because Mondays are always busy. To quote: "_Mondays are the busiest day of the week, and I am not a fast writer_". It's almost like he didn't have to write the full nomination on the day he knows is busy. There was a whole week to do so. And he's parcipitated in elections before. But I agree, his saying that he was busy absolves him of all responsibility 

Comment: So .. don't vote for him.  But painting him as "gaming the system" is an **accusation** that appears to be unwarranted.

Answer (score -34):

As you said in the comments:

> elections are largely decided by uninformed swarms of users who see notifications on the main site telling them to vote.

Absolutely agree. I think general voting is a misguided approach. Many (if not most) voters' thought process will likely go something like this:

> I see an only candidate with 40/40 score; my choice is clear. I'm giving my first priority vote to mr. Rauch, and I don't care whatever happened during nomination stage.

Comment: Err, what? You agree that "elections are largely decided by uninformed ... users", and yet you're going to base your decision solely on a single, flawed numeric metric? I am not trying to tell you that Stephen Rauch is a poor choice of candidate, but I feel that your answer is self-contradictory, and I think it represents the epitome of "uninformed" to not *at least* avail yourself of the information that *was* provided (e.g., his answers to a previous year's questionnaire), much less reading the other candidates' answers.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm just vocalizing what I assume is a thought process of many if not most voters

Comment: I see. I still think this answer is confusing, then. Maybe you should consider rephrasing? It sounds like you are advocating this approach, rather than just describing what you think is an unfortunate reality (and consequence of displaying a nearly meaningless numeric metric).

Comment: So who is your second choice? The next highest candidate score? Why did I bother writing a nice nomination summary?

Comment: @Dharman I often ask myself that about the documentation I write for services built :)

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino I've rephrased the answer to what _appears_ to be how you intended. Feel free to rollback or edit further if you think it doesn't reflect your point.

Comment: I am not sure about uninformed swarms of users. Why would uninformed swarms of users bother to vote if they have not invested (time, mentally, or otherwise) in the site? For [the stinking badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent)? (That page, by the way, leaks who voted and the exact time (resolution approx. 5 minutes) they voted (in a highly convenient place). As of 2021-10-19T164414Z+0, about 14500 users have voted (60 users per page, break at [page 242](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974?page=242) (is not stable)))

Comment: @PeterMortensen a bit like ["don't go to this link or you will crash Wikipedia"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Don%27t_stuff_beans_up_your_nose), people like to click buttons when given a choice. People also like when others ask for their input. It's very human to go vote, and people don't usually bother making informed decisions when they can make uninformed decisions (especially the users who don't want to invest time etc. in the site). I only have anecdata to back this up: a while back I saw a clearly joke candidate get startlingly close to being elected. I blame the masses.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I nearly considered voting. But then I realised I'm waaaay too ignorant of what Stack Overflow needs and decided I won't even visit the election page.